# Getting an error while extracting the data from ld+json element

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, xpath, python-requests

So I'm new to scraping and I am practicing on the retail website Trulia.com. I'm trying to extract the coordinates and zipcode from a ld+json element using its xpath, like this:

```
     for properties in search_results:
         raw_address =properties.xpath("//[@id='resultsColumn']/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/a/div[1]//text()")
         raw_area = properties.xpath("//*[@id='resultsColumn']/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div//text()")
         raw_price = properties.xpath("//*[@id='resultsColumn']/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div//text()")
         raw_data = response.xpath('//li/script[@type="application/ld+json"]//text()').extract_first()
         data = json.loads(raw_data)
         raw_zipcode = data['postalCode'][0]
         raw_latitude = data['latitude'][0]
         raw_latitude = data['longitude'][0]
```

And then when I run this for a list of zipcodes,

```
     for i in range(0,len(MI_lst)):
        scraped_data = parse(MI_lst[i])
        if scraped_data:
           if i > 0:
             append_data_to_csv(scraped_data)
           else:
             write_data_to_csv(scraped_data)
```

I get the error,

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-1a8c5a18c926> in <module>
      8 '''
      9 for i in range(0,len(MI_lst)):
---> 10     scraped_data = parse(MI_lst[i])
     11     if scraped_data:
     12         if i > 0:

<ipython-input-42-74274bded52e> in parse(zipcode, filter)
     30         #url = properties.xpath(".//a[contains(@class,'overlay-link')]/@href")
     31         #raw_title = properties.xpath(".//h4//text()")
---> 32         raw_data = response.xpath('//li/script[@type="application/ld+json"]//text()').extract_first()
     33         data = json.loads(raw_data)
     34         raw_zipcode = data['postalCode'][0]

AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

As far as I understand, I extracted the json data as text() so it shouldn't be showing this error, can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? I was trying earlier without the zipcode and coordinates, and the code ran fine for extracting the address and price.

Comment: It should be `get_element_by_xpath` but for better understanding can you update the whole code!

Comment: Hi, this is a link to the entire code so far, [link](https://file.io/pi8R1yfUSoUS)